# Analytic Characterization of Parallel Transport of Fundamental Groups

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, fundamental-group, connections

(Note that I've edited the main body of the question to make it clear for other readers.)

Fix a principal $G$-bundle $\rho: P \rightarrow X$ and fix a point $p \in P_x$ in the fiber above $x \in X$.  If $\rho$ is equipped with a flat connection $\omega$, we get a surjective homomorphism $\pi_1(X,x) \rightarrow \text{Hol}_p(\omega)$.

- When is the map $\pi_1(X, x) \rightarrow \text{Hol}_p(\omega) \hookrightarrow G \rightarrow \text{Inn}(G)$ surjective?

The motivation for this question comes from the fact that such a composition is surjective in the case of ``parallel transport'' of fundamental groups in $X$ along curves changing basepoints.

Comment: This question isn't very clear to me - what exactly do you mean by "force the situation above"? Also, my impression is that the only natural topology on $\pi_1(M)$ is the discrete topology. (I say that since it seems like $\pi_1(M)$ is the component group of the loop group of $M$.) 

Comment: Voting to close until the question actually makes sense.

Comment: I've made the appropriate changes to the question.  Does it make sense now?

Comment: The typical case is that the fundamental group is countable and $Inn(G)$ is uncountable in which case your map is never surjective.

Comment: Peter, sets of connected components may have a non-trivial totally disconnected topology, e.g. the Cantor set

Comment: If you want $G$ to be a connected compact Lie group, then the answer is "if and only of $G$ is abelian".  Incidentally, how are you defining $\operatorname{Hol}_p(\omega)$, if not as the image of $\pi_1(X,x)$ in $G$ under the monodromy map?

Comment: I believe that's what I'm taking $\text{Hol}_p(\omega)$ to be.  Fixing a fiber $P_x$ and a point $p \in P_x$ we get $P_x \cong G$.  When will holonomy around $\gamma$ correspond to conjugation by some element of $g$?  The monomorphism $\text{Hol}_p(\omega) \hookrightarrow G$ comes from $\gamma \mapsto \phi_p \in G$ for $\text{Hol}(\gamma)(p)= u \cdot \phi_p$ where $\cdot$ denotes the free transitive action of $G$ on the fibers.  Our $\text{Hol}_p(\omega)$ need not act transitively nor freely (this is how it detects the local not pointwise nature of the connection)